# join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I am making a CLI tool using python and click. I have a command called `ext` that has two options `--type` and `--path` and then another command `ext`. The function organizes the files in the specified path based on the extension specified in the given type. This is the command and the error I get:

```
Categorize ext --type image --path C:\Users\ACERq\Pictures\Screenshots ext
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'
```

I have another similar command which takes just one path option, that function works properly with the same path

```
import click
from src.services.ext_functions import *

class Context:
    def __init__(self, type, path):
        self.type = type
        self.path = path

@click.group()
@click.option("-t", "--type", type=str, help = "Type of extension", required=False, default="media")
@click.option("-p", "--path", type=str, help = "Path to organize", required=False, default=os.getcwd())
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, type, path):
    """Organize files based on extension"""
    ctx.obj = Context(type, path)
    pass

@main.command()
@click.pass_context
def ext(ctx):
    """Organize files based on specified extension types"""
    extension = ctx.obj.type
    folder_to_track = ctx.obj.path
    click.echo(extension_category(extension, folder_to_track))

@main.command()
@click.pass_context
def all(ctx):
    """Organize all files based on extension types"""
    folder_to_track = ctx.obj.path
    click.echo(all_extensions_category(folder_to_track))
```

Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\Scripts\Categorize-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('Categorize-CLI', 'console_scripts', 'Categorize')())
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python-projects\Categorize-CLI\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python-projects\categorize-cli\src\commands\ext.py", line 23, in ext
    click.echo(extension_category(extension, folder_to_track))
  File "d:\python-projects\categorize-cli\src\services\ext_functions.py", line 82, in extension_category
    folder_path = os.path.join(folder_to_track, folder_name)
  File "C:\Users\ACERq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ntpath.py", line 117, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
  File "C:\Users\ACERq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'
```

extension_category()

```
def extension_category(extension, folder_to_track):
    start_time = time.monotonic()
    movedFiles = False
    count = 0
    if check_files(folder_to_track):
        for file in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, file)):
                try:
                    file_mappings = collections.defaultdict()
                    for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                        for value in extension:
                            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)) and any(
                                    filename.endswith(value) for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track)) == True:
                                file_mappings.setdefault(get_key(extension), []).append(filename)

                    for folder_name, folder_items in file_mappings.items():
                        folder_path = os.path.join(folder_to_track, folder_name)
                        folder_exists = os.path.exists(folder_path)
                        if not folder_exists:
                            os.mkdir(folder_path)

                            for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                                for value in extension:
                                    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)) and filename.endswith(
                                            value):
                                        count = count + 1
                                        source = os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)
                                        destination = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                                        moveIncrementing(source,destination)  # move all files containing sub_file_name in their filenames
                                        movedFiles = True

                        if folder_exists:
                            for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                                for value in extension:
                                    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)) and filename.endswith(
                                            value):
                                        count = count + 1
                                        source = os.path.join(folder_to_track, filename)
                                        destination = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
                                        moveIncrementing(source,
                                                         destination)  # move all files containing sub_file_name in their filenames
                                        movedFiles = True

                    end_time = time.monotonic()

                    displayProgressbar(count)

                    if movedFiles:
                        if count == 1:
                            return f"Successfully moved {count} file{os.linesep}Time taken: {timedelta(seconds=end_time - start_time)}"
                        else:
                            return f"Successfully moved {count} files{os.linesep}Time taken: {timedelta(seconds=end_time - start_time)}"
                    else:
                        return "Files with that extension do not exist in {}".format(folder_to_track)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    return f'{folder_to_track}: is either empty or not organizable'

    else:
        return f'{folder_to_track}: is either empty or not organizable'
```

If I call the function like this: `extension_category(image, r"C:\Users\ACERq\Pictures\Screenshots")` it works

**Update**
I managed to make it work but then I encountered a new problem

[image]

When I just check if the inputted value is equal to the extension then it works but when I add some more modifications it doesn't work

[image]

Comment: You seem to have a typo somewhere, you are describing `ext` twice but I guess one of them should be `all`. Also, please include the full traceback so we don't have to guess which code path to look at.

Comment: How do you propose  for `required=False` to work when the code contains no defaults to use if the value is not supplied by the user?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee how do I make the `--type` option required for the ext command but not for the all command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem, I thought the problem was due to the parameter `folder_to_track` but it was actually the second parameter `extension` that was causing the issue. The function took the parameter as the value of the extensions-dict and not the key. So instead of `image` as the extension, it should be `[".png", ".jpg"]` etc

```
import click
from src.services.ext_functions import *

class Context:
    def __init__(self, type, path):
        self.type = type
        self.path = path

@click.command()
@click.option("-t", "--type", type=str, help = "Type of extension", required=True)
@click.option("-p", "--path", type=str, help = "Path to organize", required=False, default=os.getcwd())
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, type, path):
    """Organize files based on extension"""
    ctx.obj = Context(type, path)
    extension = ctx.obj.type
    folder_to_track = ctx.obj.path
    
    categories = [key for key, value in extensions.items()]
    if extension in categories and os.path.exists(folder_to_track):
        click.echo(extension_category(extensions[extension], folder_to_track))
    elif not extension in categories:
        click.echo("{} is not one of the types of extensions".format(extension))
    elif not os.path.exists(folder_to_track):
        click.echo("{}: does not exist".format(folder_to_track))
```